# Python model object validation

Tags: python

I'm writing an interface to be used by two applications. This interface should use some `DoSomethingRequest` and `DoSomethingResponse` classes to do the communication.

Is there any library that does some model validation, for example like Django's `Model`?

I basically want to be able to say something like:
Object A must have a "text" property of type str(), a "number" property of type int(), an "items" property of type list(). In a DRY way.

I'm looking for something like the following, or better:

```
class MyEmbeddedModelClass(EmbeddedModel):
    text = TextField(required = True)

class MyModel(Model):
    text = TextField(required = True)
    number = IntField(default = 0)
    items = ListField(EmbeddedModel)


a = MyModel()
a.text = "aaaa"
a.number = 1
a.items = [
    MyEmbeddedModelClass("bbbb"),
    MyEmbeddedModelClass("cccc"),
    MyEmbeddedModelClass("dddd")
]
a.validate()
```

I know I can write my own, but I'd rather use a library if available, I'm a bit new to this.

Comment: Why not use Django's ORM if you like it?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan : Because Django's ORM is Relational-specific, there's no  EmbeddedModel. Django's ORM also has a lot of extra stuff I don't need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to enforce interfaces, or use design-by-contract, then you probably want the  [zope.interface](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.interface/3.8.0) library. Despite the name, which reflects its origins in Zope, it's not actually tied to that framework at all and is quite usable outside.

Comment: Prody I think this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

I think decorators could be used for this.
check this link

[Combining Descriptors with Class Decorators for Validation](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1309289&seqNum=4)

For a different approach [check Duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Python)

Comment: I've done that already, but I don't like the way I must repeat the property name when setting the validator.

Comment: what about duck typing? I think is a better approach in object oriented way. You rely in other objects to use the right way your object. this a different approach, than yours not sure if you will like it.

Comment: I like duck typing, but I need to find a way to tell the people using this interface that "items" is expected to be a list of instances of type `MyEmbeddedModelClass`

Comment: Ok I understand your point of view. but in python I think (this could be personal opinion) things are different. Are you a java coder? (this is not an offensive question, I also was a java coder a lot ago). Python is a lot more object oriented than java (again my opinion). Hope this link also helps http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-interfaces-are-not-java.html

Comment: @Prody: Use a property setter on `items` that enforces `hasattr`?

Comment: @llazzaro: I know things are different, but I still don't know how to solve my problem. The closest I can think of to what I want is the way Django's ORM defines fields. I know that's not a silver bullet tho, and I'm also looking on zope.interface now.

Comment: @Daenyth: If I have two classes which have many int properties, I don't want to have to always write a setter. What if the caller doesn't even set the property?

Answer (score 0):

Because python is dynamic, the convention is to require an object to *behave* like an instance of a particular class rather than enforce a specific type.

Somewhere in your code, preferably at the point where you need to access those properties, but as early as possible assert that the object has those properties and further assert that those properties are what you expect them to be.

This raises an `AssertionError` exception if the object `o`, regardless of type, if it is missing the 'someattribute' attribute:

```
assert(hasattr(o, 'someattribute'))
```

Further, if `o.someattribute` is not a string:

```
assert(isinstance(o.someattribute, basestring))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do, but I want to do it in a `validate(self)` method automatically. In this case using TextField/IntField/etc classes.

Comment: Beware that asserts can be disabled, by calling Python with the ``-O`` flag, so they shouldn't be relied upon for flow control! Just use them as "extra checks" for testing your code..