# Python setter design pattern

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have a class like this

```
class Ownership:
    like = models.BooleanField()
    queue = models.BooleanField()
    started = models.BooleanField()
    current = models.BooleanField()
    finished = models.BooleanField()
```

It can be updated from a REST API, by putting a dict `{like:True, finished:True...}`.

At the same time, some of the fields have rules about them, e.g.:

If `like=True`, then `finished=True`. The problem I'm having is how to properly update values, when client posts, say, `{like:True, finished:False}`, here if we use a setter on like to set finished=True, then setter on finished will reset value to False.

What is a good way/design pattern that helps to clarify and solve this case?

Comment: possible solution - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7755070/813471

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you are going to have to write a validator that would return an HTTP 400 or similar in this case.  Maybe 409 is more appropriate?  In either case you could include an error string to explain which key/value combination caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default save method to validate and change the values

```
class Ownership:
    like = models.BooleanField()
    queue = models.BooleanField()
    started = models.BooleanField()
    current = models.BooleanField()
    finished = models.BooleanField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.like:
            self.finished = True
        super(Ownership, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method
```